# is there way to get version and encoding from xml document?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, match

I am using regular expression to get version and encoding from xml document.

````
let xmlString = "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1""

var match = xmlString.match(/version(\s)*=(\s)*\"(?<version>.{3})\".*encoding(\s)*=(\s)*\"(?<encoding>.*)$/);```

but getting invalid Group error:

Error: Invalid regular expression: /version(\s)*=(\s)*\"(?<version>.{3})\".*encoding(\s)*=(\s)*\"(?<encoding>.*)$/: **Invalid group**
````

Comment: Your xmlString looks strange. Why are double quotes not excaped?

Answer (score 0):

I corrected the quotes around `xmlString` and removed unnecessary parentheses and backslashes in the regular expression.

**UPD**: I also replaced named groups with anonymous. They are relatively recent addition to ECMAScript (2018) and are probably not supported by your node.js.

```js
let xmlString = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"'

var match = xmlString.match(/version\s*=\s*"(.{3})".*encoding\s*=\s*"(.*)"$/);

console.log(match[1]);
```